# sigqueue with ctypes always returning -1

Tags: python, signals, ctypes

I'm trying to use [`sigqueue`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sigqueue.3.html) with python, but it always returns -1.

```
import os
import signal
from ctypes import *

c = cdll.LoadLibrary("libc.so.6")
c.sigqueue(c_int(os.getpid()), c_int(signal.SIGUSR2), 0) #returns -1
```

If I try to use an union, it also fails:

```
class sig_value(Union):
    _fields_ = [("sival_int", c_int), ("sival_ptr", c_void_p)]
v = sig_value()
v.sival_int = 0
c.sigqueue(c_int(os.getpid()), c_int(signal.SIGUSR2), v) #returns -1
```

What could I be missing?

Comment: What does *errno* tell you?  Be sure to use `CDLL('libc.so.6', use_errno=True)` and `ctypes.get_errno()` to retrieve it.  Also try setting `.argtypes` properly: `c.sigqueue.argtypes = c_int,c_int,sig_value`.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! Got ENOSYS (function not implemented). Tried in a truly linux machine and it worked.